How to add a dynamic timer on top of a saved video
I have a code where I'm adding a timer label as a subview on my view but that timer label obviously stays just on view, not in the video that is recorded and saved, I have tried multiple things but everything has been in vain, does anyone have an idea how this can be done?

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var timer: Timer?
    var startTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var isRecording = false
    var recordButton: UIButton!
    var timerLabel: UILabel!
    let player = AVQueuePlayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkCameraAuthorization()
        checkPhotoLibraryAuthorization()
        checkMicrophoneAuthoization()
        
        setupCamera()
        setupUI()
        
        // Set up audio session for volume control
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        } catch {
            print("Error setting up audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func setupCamera() {
        // Setup capture session
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .high
        
        // Add input device
        guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
              let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera) else { return }
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        
        // Add audio input device
        guard let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio),
              let audioInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone) else {
            print("Failed to create audio input.")
            return
        }
        captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
        
        // Add output
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        
        // Setup preview layer
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        // Start the session
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            self?.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        // Record button
        recordButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        recordButton.frame = CGRect(x: (view.bounds.width - 60) / 2, y: view.bounds.height - 100, width: 60, height: 60)
        recordButton.backgroundColor = .white
        recordButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        recordButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleRecording), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(recordButton)
        
        // Timer label
        timerLabel = UILabel()
        timerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.bounds.width, height: 20)
        timerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        timerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        timerLabel.textColor = .white
        view.addSubview(timerLabel)
    }
    
    @objc func toggleRecording() {
        if !isRecording {
            // Start recording
            startRecording()
        } else {
            // Stop recording
            stopRecording()
        }
        
        // Toggle recording state
        isRecording = !isRecording
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        // Start recording
        let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let filename = "video_\(Int(timestamp)).mov"
        let outputPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + filename
        let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
        
        if videoOutput.isRecording {
            print("Already recording.")
            return
        }
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        dispatchGroup.enter() // Enter the dispatch group before starting the recording
        
        // Start recording
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.videoOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
            print("Video is recording")
            dispatchGroup.leave() // Leave the dispatch group after starting the recording
        }
        
        // Play custom sound
        playCustomSound()
        
        // Start timer
        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(updateElapsedTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        // Update button color
        recordButton.backgroundColor = .red
        
        // Wait for all tasks to finish
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            // All tasks are finished
        }
        
    }
    
    func stopRecording() {
        // Get output URL before stopping the recording
        // let outputURL = videoOutput.outputFileURL
        
        // Stop recording
        videoOutput.stopRecording()
        
        print("Recording has been stopped.")
        
        // Stop timer
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        // Update button color
        recordButton.backgroundColor = .white
        
    }
    
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputFileURL)
        }) { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func playCustomSound() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "startsound", withExtension: "m4a") else {
                print("Sound file not found.")
                return
            }
            do {
                let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
                self?.player.removeAllItems()
                self?.player.insert(item, after: nil)
                self?.player.play()
                print("Audio playback started.")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc func updateElapsedTime() {
        let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime
        
        let milliseconds = Int(elapsedTime * 1000) % 1000
        let seconds = Int(elapsedTime) % 60
        let minutes = (Int(elapsedTime) / 60) % 60
        
        let formattedTime = String(format: "%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
        timerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        timerLabel.text = "\(formattedTime)"
    }
    
    func checkPhotoLibraryAuthorization() {
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            // User has authorized access to the photo library.
            print("Photo library access authorized.")
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request photo library access.
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
                if status == .authorized {
                    print("Photo library access granted.")
                } else {
                    print("Photo library access denied.")
                }
            }
        case .denied, .restricted:
            // Photo library access is denied or restricted.
            print("Photo library access denied or restricted.")
        case .limited: // Handle the .limited case
            print("Photo library access limited.")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown authorization status.")
        }
    }
    
    func checkCameraAuthorization() {
        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            // User has authorized access to the camera.
            print("Camera access authorized.")
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request camera access.
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
                if granted {
                    print("Camera access granted.")
                } else {
                    print("Camera access denied.")
                }
            }
        case .denied, .restricted:
            // Camera access is denied or restricted.
            print("Camera access denied or restricted.")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown authorization status.")
        }
    }
    
    func checkMicrophoneAuthoization() {
        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio)
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            // User has authorized access to the microphone.
            print("Microphone access authorized.")
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request microphone access.
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
                if granted {
                    print("Microphone access granted.")
                } else {
                    print("Microphone access denied.")
                }
            }
        case .denied, .restricted:
            // Microphone access is denied or restricted.
            print("Microphone access denied or restricted.")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown authorization status.")
        }
    }
}


I've already tried doing by adding it to the frames but it doesn't work at all.

did you get solution for this?

nothing so far.
